# kill thread forcefully C++ win32

Tags: c++, win32com

I have created a thread with this line

```
threadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, FALSE, Threadhandle1, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

I want to kill thread forcefully without waiting for a thread to finish

Thread Code:-

```
DWORD WINAPI Threadhandle1(void* data){
    Sleep(5000);
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("First"), L"Simple Message", NULL);
    Sleep(5000);
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Second"), L"Simple Message", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Code to Stop Thread:-

```
TerminateThread(threadHandle, 0);
CloseHandle(threadHandle);
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686724(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have used TerminateThread(threadHandle, 0); for terminating thread but its not working

Comment: Have you checked if the threadHandle is a correct handle and that the other thread has: 
The handle must have the THREAD_TERMINATE access right. For more information, see Thread Security and Access Rights.

Comment: Thanks for help Lucian there is some error with threadHandle

Answer (score 0):

You can terminate thread by  using TerminateThread() using the thread handle you got from CreateThread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717(VS.85).aspx

PS:It is mentioned in website:
"TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination."

Comment: I have used TerminateThread(threadHandle, 0); for terminating thread but its not working